# VS Code turns everything into an html snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code

a serious limitation for my workflow with vs code is the fact that while typing html everything gets turned into an html tag when pressing tab at the beginning of a line.

entering:

alsdjflkasjdfk + Tab

leads to:

```
<alsdjflkasjdfk> </alsdjflkasjdfk>
```

this is a problem since I want to integrate Django html snipptes and they end up not working. Does someone know how to turn this off? I rather just want defined HTML Snipptes than simply everything turning into one.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": false
```

This should disable this feature. We are also investigating a different flow for emmet with VSCode 1.12: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21943